# framer motion exist transition is not working

Tags: reactjs, transition, exit, framer-motion, unmount

```
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
<AnimatePresence>
  {isOpen && (
   <motion.div
     key="modal"
     ref={sheetRef}
     initial={{ y: '100%' }}
     animate={{
       y: '0%',
      transition: { duration: 0.2, ease: 'linear' },
     }}
     exit={{
      y: '100%',
      transition: { duration: 0.2, ease: 'linear' },
     }}
  >
  .......
  </motion.div>
))</AnimatePresence>
```

The exist transition is not working while I close the sheet. [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/framer-motion-animate-presence-example-forked-mxgctw)

Comment: What about it isn't working? Saying "it's not working" doesn't help us help you. With the limited code you provided, I recreated [this example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/framer-motion-animate-presence-example-7d5ng2) that is working. Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The existing transition effect is not working when we import the above sheet into a different component.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/framer-motion-animate-presence-example-forked-mxgctw is of not working code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the conditional rendering around your `<Sheet />` component.
You have conditional rendering logic in two places:

App.tsx

```
// Not needed
{isOpen && (
    <Sheet isOpen={isOpen} />
)}
```

Sheet.tsx

```
<AnimatePresence>
    {isOpen && (
        <motion.div ...>
        ...
        </motion.div>
     )}
</AnimatePresence>
```

This is reduntant and causing the exit animation to not work because the rendering logic around `<Sheet />` is immediately removing `<Sheet />` from the React tree. The logic within your `<Sheet />` component is the correct logic, according to the [framer motion docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/##exit-animations).

Here is an [updated working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/framer-motion-animate-presence-example-forked-rgxwqf?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A12%2C18).